# Core Data Migration using Mapping Model

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I currently have a model where the relationship between two entities is many-to-many

```
Player <---->> Team
Team   <---->> Player
```

To be able to support ordering, I am planning to use an intermediate entity TeamToPlayer. I can't use the new iOS5 Ordered property since I need to support older versions.

```
Player <---->> TeamToPlayer
Team   <---->> TeamToPlayer
```

My TeamToPlayer is defined as follows

```
TeamToPlayer
   NSInteger order
   Team* team
   Player *player
```

Now, I am trying to migrate the old relationship into this new one and not sure how to proceed. I created the Core data mapping model but not sure how to define the expressions for the relationships.
Also, the mapping model created entity mapping for all entities in my core data model. Is it necessary to have the entity mappings for all entities or the ones that needs migration.

Thanks,
Javid